# Monitor VyOS Router

Tags: router, vyos

I'm actually using VyOS 1.1.8 an i wan't to collect the eth0 interface traffic to send it to a centralized syslog server. The thing is that i want to have the net traffic in some format like squid uses in access.log file.I'll apreciate your help?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "interface traffic," do you mean byte/packet counters?

Comment: no just kinda http://www.facebook.com/

Comment: monitor interfaces ethernet eth* traffic gives you this 0.715602 10.46.200.20 -> 190.92.112.15 TCP 43241 > 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=631329 Win=786 Len=0 TSV=3930033038 TSER=664784420
  0.715609 10.46.200.20 -> 190.92.112.15 TCP [TCP Dup ACK 973#1] 43241 > 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=631329 Win=786 Len=0 TSV=3930033038

Comment: what i want is more like this

Comment: You want packet captures.  That will put a heavy load on the router.

Comment: 1531860444.579  68865 10.46.27.28 TCP_MISS/200 2522 CONNECT static.xx.fbcdn.net:443 ogotu9 DIRECT/31.13.67.20 -
1531860444.678    954 10.46.10.99 TCP_MISS/200 2269 GET http://support.huawei.com/hedexweb/hedex/upgradeAction.do? -

Comment: the thing is that i want a more friendly understantable trace

Comment: Do you use NAT? You can add a "log enable" statement in the NAT rule and then use the standard linux syslog. But everythins is logged into /var/log/messages. You can see what it looks like with the "show log nat" command .

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

VyOs is linux-based, and like Squid, use iptables, so yes you can have exactly the same result.

You can log the traffic using a "log" statement in a firewall rule.

Basically if you accept all traffic then this will do the job:

> set firewall name log-all rule 1 action permit
>   set firewall name log-all rule 1 log enable
>   set interfaces ethernet eth0 firewall in name log-all

If you have different firewall rules, simply add the  `log enable` statement to each.

Then use the standard syslog facilities to send the log to your central syslog server.

Note that:

- VyOs support NetFlow and sFlow, which may have less impact on performance, but will give different results.
- if you perform NAT on this interface you can also log the NAT translation with, again, a  `log enable` statement in the NAT rules